# How do I solve network troubles with a wireless webcam?

Tags: network-camera

Simple problem. I have an old (almost antique) [Linksys WVC54G Internet Video Camera](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/support/WVC54G/download). I used it in the past, then it disappeared in some closet for about 5, 6 years. In the meantime, I also made some small adjustments to my home network. A second router was added and all computers were moved from 192.168.1.* to 192.168.168.*. (With one exception.)
Recently, one of the routers was removed again but I just keep everything configured at 192.168.168.*. (Especially since I have a bunch of virtual machines which I don't want to reconfigure.)

Recently, I took this camera out of the closet again, reconnected it to my network and discovered that it wants to use 192.168.1.115 instead of any address in the 192.168.168.* range. The router doesn't pick up the device and it seems to have the IP address fixed thus I can't change it. I've tried to reset the device but it remembers the "wrong" address.

So, is there any way that I can reconnect to this camera again without having to reconfigure my router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be some default IP for that Wireless CAM. Please check [this](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-use-linksys-compact-wireless-g-internet-video-camera-wvc54gc-from-linux/) Link. It is explained in detail.

Comment: +1 While the instructions are linux specific, the method is the same.  You need to change a computer's IP to one that is on the same subnet. (192.168.1.X, and a mask of 255.255.255.0)  You will then be able to connect to the webcam in a browser where you can change the IP to the normal network.

Comment: Actually, abou 8 years ago, I configured the camera to use that IP address. Now I'm regretting that decision. It's not the default, unfortunately.

Comment: @Alex: Are these steps not working now?

Comment: Nope. For whatever reasons the camera remembered the settings even after a reset and about being plugged off for 5 years... Btw, I don't want to change the subnet of my router to just fix an old camera. It's not worth that much trouble...

Comment: @Alex: Hmmm... Valid point.. agreed... You said one router was removed. Do you have it still anywhere? If so, you could try configuring it and then connecting the cam to it then changing IP.. Just a thought :)

Comment: Yes, I have the old router. Unfortunately, it's defective. The lights just don't go on anymore. This model camera isn't expensive enough to adjust my current router, considering it's age and the price of current cams. Basically, if I don't get it to work, I'll buy a new one instead. :-)

Comment: @Alex: Okie :).. Got it